# HashMap or TreeMap for small set sizes

Tags: java, dictionary

I understand the time complexity of HashMap vs TreeMap, but what about small set sizes  in critical code paths ? (average of 4 ?)

The question I have is.. for which set size does: `O(1) < O(lg(n))`?

For a set size of 1, the lookup time for a TreeMap should be faster than for a HashMap.

What about a size of 8? When will `log(n)` be slower than the constant hash-lookup time ?

Comment: Evidently you don't understand time complexity at all. This is an _asymptotic_ result. The constant factors are ignored, the smaller factors are dropped. `HashMap` will (almost) always be faster, it simply does less work. In any case, the answer will depend on your particular objects, your particular `compareTo` and `equals` and `hashCode` implementations. Your particular usage of the constructs. **BENCHMARK**.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I am asking for a practical answer. I know that in terms of time complexity the constant factors are ignored, but that doesn't mean they don't exists and aren't important for practical applications.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, that is a good point though, I didn't describe what we're hashing.

Comment: If you want a practical answer, my answer it is same. A `HashMap` depends on the speed of `equals` and `hashCode`. A `TreeMap` depends on the speed of `compareTo`. So, back to my original answer - set up Caliper and run a few dozen benchmarks.

Comment: The time to compute the hash and the size required for the hashtable are offset in a treemap lookup.  Hash maps are big - they have to be to minimize collisions.  If you're using a bunch of hash maps, you're using up a lot of memory, which means your footprint is bigger.  Bigger foot print increases the likelihood of page faults.

You can do a lot of treemap lookup in the time it takes to do a single page fault.

Comment: You can run empirical tests for your particular situation, but in general, if the number is small (< 30 or so), a treemap is efficient enough.  If you start getting up into the hundreds or thousands, a hash table is going to be a better solution.  For small stuff, I almost always use a treemap.